# Using cpio, is it possible to change filepaths when extracting?

Tags: bash, unix, path, centos, cpio

generally, I'd execute `rpm2cpio $rpm | cpio -idmv` but this extracts the exact file paths into the local folder

i.e

```
./usr/local/mycompany/myapp/bin/app
./usr/local/mycompany/myapp/resource/...
```

Is it possible to rewrite the file paths during the extract so that they instead extract to

```
./myapp/bin/app
./myapp/resource/...
```

Comment: Can't whatever creates the archive do so using paths relative to `./usr/local/mycompany` rather than you having to strip that leading part of the path when extracting the files?

Comment: Unable to modify the creation of the archive sadly @EdMorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to rewrite the file paths during the extract

GNU `cpio` offers the `-r` option to *interactively* rename files during extraction ("copy in").  But I suppose you want something automatic and / or scriptable, and there is no documented `cpio` feature providing for that.

But it should be fast and straightforward to just move the subtree you want after the extraction, and then remove the extra, presumably empty parent directories:

```
mv ./usr/local/mycompany/myapp .
test "$(realpath .)" != / && rm -rf ./usr
```

That adds a little protection against catastrophe arising from running those commands from the filesystem root as a privileged user, but overall, you should not run it with privilege.